# CSS 3d-Button "onclick"-event not working on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with 3d-Buttons. But they are not clickable on top or better the css-transformation is working, but the "onclick"-event is not activating... It is only not working in the area, where the button goes down and is not anymore there..

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo() called');
}
```

```css
/** CSS **/

.clicky {
    /** Offset the Position **/
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    /** 3D Block Effect **/
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 #6B2A4A;

    /** Make it look pretty **/
    display: block;
    background: #a47;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.clicky:active {
    /** Remove 3D Block Effect on Click **/
    box-shadow: none;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.clicky:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.clicky:active,
.clicky:focus {
    /** Remove Chrome's Ugly Yellow Outline **/
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="clicky" onclick="foo();">CLICK ME!</button>
```

Is it possible, that the "onclick"-event is also trigger when the user clicks the 3d-Button on the top?

It would be great if someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: what is top here? while clicking it works fyn

Comment: @rakael Your question is not clear.. what do you want? what is top and bottom, we cannot understand this way. Also where is you on click javascript function? Add more and clear details.

Comment: I moved the code into a snippet, there it is clear what he meant: clicking at the top of the button, it those have the click effect, but the event doesn't fire

Comment: I think he has written in css by using active and focus for clickable event.No need js

Comment: Clicking on bottom shadow event not firing, but I did't find  on top

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.. Sorry my english is not perfect, maybe i explained it a bit wrong..
So normally when the button is clicked, then the foo()-function is called.. But when you click on the pixels on top of the button, then the css transformations works correctly but the foo() is not called then.
i mean the 2 dimensional top of the button :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because by moving the position of the button down `10px` (`top:10px` in your `:active` css class) you are moving it out of the way of the mouse. If the mouse is released without moving back into the hitbox of the button, the mouse event (in this case `mouseup`) will be triggered on whatever is now underneath the mouse instead of a `click` event on the button.

What you could do is make a container for the button, like a `<div>`, and put the event handler on it. Note the event will need to be `mouseup` as `click` will not be triggered in this situation on either element.

```
<div onmouseup="foo()">
  <button class="clicky">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
```

Demo, note I changed the `.clicky:active` class to `.click:active, div.active .clicky` to make it so clicking on the drop shadow will also cause the css change

```js
function foo(){
 alert('foo called');
}
```

```css
div {
  padding-bottom:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.clicky {
    /** Offset the Position **/
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    /** 3D Block Effect **/
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 #6B2A4A;

    /** Make it look pretty **/
    display: block;
    background: #a47;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.clicky:active, div:active .clicky {
    /** Remove 3D Block Effect on Click **/
    box-shadow: none;
    top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.clicky:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.clicky:active,
.clicky:focus {
    /** Remove Chrome's Ugly Yellow Outline **/
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseup="foo()">
  <button class="clicky">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is for sure a possibility. But i tried this too and now the whole area next of the button on the right side is also calling the function..
Is there no other possibility, where the event takes the reference area before the css transformation is done?

Comment: @rakael, You can change the container's style, for instance changing it's display property to inline-block should make it fit to the button. Edited demo to reflect

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! This works totally fine :-)

Answer (score 3):

add this class in your style. Then the top click will work on press button

```
.clicky:active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

See the Snippet

```js
function foo() {
  alert('Clicked');
}
```

```css
.clicky {
  /** Offset the Position **/
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /** 3D Block Effect **/
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 #6B2A4A;
  /** Make it look pretty **/
  display: block;
  background: #a47;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.clicky:active {
  /** Remove 3D Block Effect on Click **/
  box-shadow: none;
  top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.clicky:active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.clicky:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.clicky:active,
.clicky:focus {
  /** Remove Chrome's Ugly Yellow Outline **/
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="clicky" onclick="foo()">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is excactly what i was searching for. :-))

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding I guess you want the foo() to fire when clicking on the button's shadow too.To achieve this, try placing the button inside a div which includes the button's shadow too and give the onclick () for this div.By this you can achive both the css transformations as well the foo() event firing also.